# Adding 3rd party libraries in CLI app - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a CLI app made in swift through Xcode 7.3 beta 2 and Swift 2.2. I'm trying to add a library in my app called OAuthSwift by manually copying it and adding it in my target.

Trying to run the app, I keep on getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vapor-bxotywnuvdhyupfqfmhdgtykiqlj/Build/Products/Debug/OAuthSwift.framework/Versions/A/OAuthSwift
  Reason: image not found
```

Would any of you know how to get around this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope, sorry @TimVermeulen